# Passing a mutable object into a Python subroutine vs a scalar variable

Tags: python

I originally solved a question of LeetCode, No. [543](https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/) Diameter of Binary Tree, with the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        res = [0] 
        def depth(root, res):
            if not root:
                return 0
            left = depth(root.left, res)
            right = depth(root.right, res)
            res[0] = max(res[0], left + right) 
            return max(left, right) + 1
        depth(root, res)    
        return res[0]
```

I am wondering why the solution is wrong if I replace the list `res` with declaring a generic integer variable instead just like the solution below:

```
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        res = 0 
        def depth(root, res):
            if not root:
                return 0
            left = depth(root.left, res)
            right = depth(root.right, res)
            res = max(res, left + right) 
            return max(left, right) + 1
        depth(root, res)    
        return res
```

Is it just because lists are mutable and scalars are not? Can anyone explain it?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question...

Comment: Some terminology notes, "scalar" isn't really a term used in Python. You have an `int` object. And note, you *do not declare variables in Python*. Variables pop into existence when they are assigned to, and variables are not typed. Objects have types, and variables can refer to any object of any type.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether ints are mutable. It's the difference between assigning to a variable and assigning to a part of an object.

Comment: The first version would also fail if you changed `res[0] = max(res[0], left + right)` to `res = [max(res[0], left + right)]` because you're creating a new list instead of modifying the original list.

Comment: However, the fact that ints are immutable means there's no way to modify the value of `res` in place so it affects the caller's variable as well. You have to use mutable containers for that.